# DBI or odbc package for SQL server

Tags: r, odbc, r-dbi

We are moving away from RODBC which seems to have a limited error handling system (sometimes to query goes through even though there was an error, and there is no way to get the error message. we have tried all RODBC functions)

However there seem to be 2 packages similar: odbc and DBI, Can someone explain what is the difference between the two? Both seem to work well.

Comment: Check this out: http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2017/08/a-modern-database-interface-for-r.html

Comment: @tomaz thanks for the link that provides a nice background, however it does not explain why one would need to use `odbc` when underlying package `DBI` seems to do same (with same function names)

Comment: I think `odbc` will translate dplyr code to SQL and run it on the database and `DBI` won't.

Comment: ok thanks that would makes sense.

Comment: What I don't really understand is if they are trying to make their commands compatible. It's totally confusing, at least that's my impression.

Answer (score 1):

look at the odbc github
https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc#reading

They compare with the RSQLServer package and the odbc package seems to be faster.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.